# Service activator not processing the message from channel after getting the soapfaultException

Tags: spring-integration

I am using the JMS inbound channel adapter which is consuming the messages from MQ and sending these messages to a channel. This channel is sending this message to a service activator and the SAis parsing this message and sending the object to the WS outbound gateway which will call a web service.

the Adapter is reading 50 messages after every 30 seconds and the service activator is sending them to WS outbound gateway.
If the WS call is success then all the messages are processing successfully and if the WS is sending soapFaultException in that case Service activator is not processing rest of the messages and process them in next round i.e. after 30 secs, Not sure why. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume only one scenario:

1. Your JMS Inbound Channel Adapter is configured with `poller` for `max-messages-per-poll="0"`
2. Therefore it polls in one JMS transaction as much messages as possible and sends them one by one to the channel.
3. Since all of them are processed in the same thread, they are confirmed (acked, commited) into JMS only after the whole bunch.
4. Having at least one exception during the batch process means rollback all messages to the queue.

You can process them in parallel using a `taskExecutor` or even better switch to the Message Driven Channel Adapter, where a TX around one message won't affect all others.

Comment: Thanks Artem.your assumption is correct.I was using Message Driven Channel Adapter but I need to consume the queue after every 15 mins,and I could not get any way to configure that fixed rate, So is it possible with Message Driven Channel Adapter?

Comment: Well, if you have such a requirement , I can suggest you different solution. Place ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice on your service activator and with any error re-send message failed message back to the queue. So, any good messages won't be affected and will be still confirmed on the JMS Broker.

Comment: I got one more solution. I used the int:aggregator and this aggregator is sending the List<String> queueMessageList to my service activator. Iterating on the list and sending to the channel by send method and I put this send method inside the try and catch block and this is working.so the flow is like inbound-channel-adapter - >inputChannel->int:aggregator->RouteAggrChannel->Service Activator . This service activator will get the List<String> queueMessageList

Comment: OK. That's fine, too. Not so generic from the Integration perspective, but it is your solution! I guess, we've done with the question. What do you need else in my answer to get accept from you?